# Ability to access cookies "cleanly" in test environment

Tags: python, cookies, flask

How would I go about testing my app for cookies which have been set during a request in a way that's pythonic? The way I currently do it (which works) doesn't feel very convenient, but here it is:

```
def test_mycookie(app, client):
    def getcookie(name):
        try:
            cookie = client.cookie_jar._cookies['mydomain.dev']['/'][name]
        except KeyError:
            return None
        else:
            return cookie

    with app.test_request_context():
        client.get('/non-existing-path/')
        assert getcookie('mycookie') is None
        client.get('/')
        assert getcookie('mycookie').value == '"xyz"'
```

Using `flask.request.cookies` doesn't work for me as it always returns an empty dict. Maybe I'm doing it wrong?

```
def test_mycookie2(app, client):

    with app.test_request_context():
        client.get('/non-existing-path/')
        assert 'mycookie' not in request.cookies
        client.get('/')
        request.cookies['mycookie']  # Raises KeyError
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? use `app.test_client` will let us keep the context little longer.

```
with app.test_client() as tc:
    tc.get('/non-existing-path/')
    assert 'mycookie' not in request.cookies
    tc.get('/')
    print request.cookies['mycookie']
```

also, please give us a minimal example that can works so that we can reproduce this problem.